# How can you change an IIS Site's App Pool with the Powershell Web Admin Commandlets

Tags: iis, powershell

The following code demonstrates what I thought might work, but it doesn't change the app pool - it remains set at its current value (even though the $site object does update):

```
import-module WebAdministration

$site = get-item "IIS:\Sites\Project"
$site.ApplicationPool = "ProjectAppPool"
$site | set-item
```

If you create the site with New-WebSite specifying the -ApplicationPool parameter, it creates as expected.  What Powershell IIS web command must I use to change an *existing* site's app pool to something different?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

ApplicationPool is a property on the web site in the IIS: drive. Set it like so:

```
#site level
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' applicationPool ProjectAppPool

#app level
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\AppName' applicationPool ProjectAppPool
```

If you have the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) installed, you can use the Show-Tree command to explore these drives e.g.:

```
Show-Tree IIS:\Sites -ShowProperty -Depth 1
```

Comment: I have found the "Application Pool" property is case sensitive, and that you need to change ApplicationPool to application pool. e.g. Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\AppName' applicationPool ProjectAppPool

Comment: Need to `Import-Module WebAdministration` before the `Get-ItemProperty` and `Set-ItemProperty` commands are available.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this worked. Important *Start* and *Stop* commit delay:

```
Start-IISCommitDelay
$ThisSite = Get-IISSite "whatever"
$ThisSite.Applications["/"].ApplicationPoolName = $poolName
Stop-IISCommitDelay
```